# Running f sharp compiler under .net core

Tags: f#, .net-core

I would like to know how to run the f sharp compiler from the command line under .net core. I know I can create a .sln, then use dotnet restore etc. That works fine.

I am using the docker version of .net core (microsoft/dotnet), and note that fsc.exe is downloaded by nuget deep into /root/.nuget. However, there isn't any obvious way of running it from there.

I have a scripted build-process (for some command-line application) that runs under both MS .net and mono. The easiest way of adding .net core support is to just modify the compilation command in that script to run f sharp under docker/.net core. I guess I also need to know how to then run the produced executable (assuming it's non-obvious once I know how to run the compiler).

If the only way of compiling f# code under .net core involves the dotnet utility, can someone please tell me why it's necessary (i.e. why the usual flow available under .net/mono of just running fsc and getting an executable won't work)? Many thanks.

Comment: If the down-voter would have the courtesy to tell me what is wrong with the question, I would appreciate it. I want to do something the documentation does not explain, and there is no obvious reason for why it would not be possible. It's trivial to run the command line compiler under both mono and .net. Why not .net core?

Comment: I was under the impression that F# in .NET Core is in the "not yet supported but coming soon" realm, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Supported can mean different things to different people. F# is not yet supported under Visual Studio. However, it is certainly usable if you are willing to hand-edit .sln/.proj files (easy, though not great for maintaining large projects that also need to build under MSVS). https://github.com/dotnet/netcorecli-fsc/wiki/FAQ Anyhow, I would be happy to instead learn how to run the C# compiler from the command line under .net core?

Comment: Oh, I can help you with that. There's a `dotnet` command which you use for everything: in a nutshell, `dotnet restore` (restore packages), `dotnet build` (compile), `dotnet test` (run unit tests). See [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/).

Comment: @gigi Yes, I am aware of the "dotnet" command, and say so in the question. But that command is clearly meant for interactive use as it e.g. creates example .fs files for humans to edit. I am looking for an easy to use an existing buildscript. I could just generate a .fsproj file, then use "dotnet build". But it would still be good to understand why that's the only way.  The command-line interface of the f# compiler works really well for me under .net and mono.